# Do we have $a\sin x+b\cos x=c\sin (x+d)$ with $a,b,c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

In showing that the set 
$$
W=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}\mid f(x)=a\sin(x+b),a\in\mathbb{C},b\in\mathbb{R}\}
$$
forms a complex vector space, I need to answer the following question:

> Given $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$, are there $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and $d\in\mathbb{R}$ such that  $a\sin x+b\cos x=c\sin (x+d)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

It is known that this is true when $a$ and $b$ are both real. But I'm not sure about the complex case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sin(x+d) = \cos(d)\sin(x) + \sin(d)\cos(x)$, so you want $a = c \cos(d)$ and $b = c \sin(d)$.  In particular, if $a \ne 0$ we need $\dfrac{b}{a} = \tan(d) \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that since this is conditionally true, $W$ might not be a complex vector space.